# Clojure: compare characters

Tags: clojure

In C++ world, I can do like this (characters are comparable):

```
bool isDigit(char c) {
  return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
}
```

In Clojure, I can compare for equality, but can compare with less:

```
(= \a \b) ; [compiles] false
(< \a \b) ; java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

How can I implement this in Clojure? How can I check if a character in a range? I can do it in heavy-weight style like this:

```
(defn isDigit [c] (#{\0 \1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9} c))
```

Comment: Characters are comparable in Clojure. Use `compare`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `int` coercion if you want to check whether a character falls in some range:

```
(let [zero (int \0)
      nine (int \9)]
  (defn is-digit? [c] (<= zero (int c) nine)))
```

Alternatively, you could call directly to the `Character.isDigit` method, if all you need to check for is digits. Clearly that won't work for ranges that aren't predefined character classes.

Comment: `defn` inside `let`... do you use it to optimize `is-digit?` calculating once `zero` and `nine`? So, in my `isDigit` can I put set in `let` to construct it once?

Comment: Yes, I did that to avoid doing the int coercion on `\0` and `\9` every time. In the case of your `isDigit`, it wouldn't matter, because your use of the set literal `#{}` means the set is constructed by the reader. It would only make sense to use `let` if you were creating the set programmatically e.g. with `hash-set`.

Answer (score 4):

```
(defn digit? [c] (and (>= 0 (compare \0 c)) 
                      (>= 0 (compare c \9))))

(defn digit?? [c] (= (java.lang.Character/getType ^Character c)
                     (java.lang.Character/DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER)))

(defn digit??? [c] (re-find #"\d" (str c)))
```

Comment: Should probably use re-matches instead of re-find since we're only interested in matching the entire string.

Comment: Yes, `digit???` allows not only chars - strings as well and match seems to be suitable here.

Comment: @Webb First one is what I need. Both of solutions I see are good.